# Regular expressions search returning "nonetype"

Tags: python

Ok, so I've been trying to make a program to search between these 2 parameters: "MA(7):" and "MA(25):". I have made programs that use the re.search function in the past, but this one is stubborn and doesn't work. The code is as follows:

```
import pyautogui
import pyscreenshot as LemonGrab
import pytesseract
import cv2
import re
import regex

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
pattern = r" MA(7): (.*) MA(25): "

while True:
    text = 'MA(7): Hello find this MA(25):'
    token = (re.search(pattern, text, re.IGNORECASE))
    if token is None:
        pass
    else:
        tog = token.group()
        tog = str(tog)
        print(tog)
        break
```

I honestly have no idea why other programs search but this one doesn't. I have tried everything I can think of and searched as many sites as I can. Help!
Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Why does your pattern starts and ends with spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expression I used: 
`r"MA\(7\): (.*) MA\(25\):"` 
You might want to remove the spaces on the ends of the pattern as that is what I did and it seemed to work fine although I did have to do `token[1]` to get the `Hello find this` part

Comment: You are an actual legend! Thank you!